# Add a java project into an rcp plugin's classpath

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-rcp, classpath

I have a java project and imported plug-in in my workspace and I'd like to add the project to plug-in's classpath. I know that it's possible by exporting the project to jar file and then importing it in plug-in's manifest, but when I make a change in project I have to export it again. Is there a way to add java project instead of jar file to the plug-in's classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Your Eclipse IDE does resolve two kinds of plugins/fragments/features:

1. Those located in your workspace and
2. those you have in your target platform

The plugins in your target platform are usually the one which come along as a JAR (expanded is also possible).

To add your java project as a dependency of your plugin, you have to change the project to be a plugin by adding `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to the root of your project.

Content could be as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyBundleName
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.mybundlename
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
```

As a plus you should export the packages with your API-classes

```
Export-Package: com.example.mypackage
```

Finally you have to define the enhanced java project as a dependency in your plugin.
Open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of your plugin edit "Required Plugins" in Tab "Dependencies".

---

**Update:**

You can add class folders to the classpath of your plugin.
To do so open the properties of your plugin (rightclick plugin > 'Properties'), choose 'Java Build Path', 'Add Class Folder...' and add the folder(s) which contain(s) your classes (e.g. 'bin').

Comment: Ok. The point was that I didn't want to change my project to plugin and I wanted to get its classes directly from workspace to another plugin. So I understand that this solution isn't possible.

Comment: Of course you can, but it will be a rather inconvenient way in my opinion. I will update my answer.

Comment: @alphakermit how can you add clases / files to the classpath of another bundle?